# UICollectionView custom cell's subview is nil even though linked from Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I created a view controller programmatically. I don't use Storyboard because this view controller is to be presented by multiple view controllers and I don't like to make my Storyboard look too complicated.

This view controller contains a `UICollectionView`, whose cells are customized via Storyboard, called `CustomCell.xib`, which has nothing but an `UIImageView` as a subview.

Then, I created a `CustomCell.swift` file and made it the file owner of `CustomCell.xib`. I also dragged and linked `UIImageView` to `CustomCell.swift`:

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    prepareForReuse() {
        imageView.image = nil
    }
}
```

Then, in my view controller's `viewDidLoad` and `cellForItemAt`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    let myCollectionView = UICollectionView.init(frame: view.bounds,
                                                 collectionViewLayout: layout)

    myCollectionView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    view.addSubview(myCollectionView)
}

cellForItemAt(...) {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell",
                                                  for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    cell.imageView.image = ...        // <---"imageView" is nil when running, why?

    return cell
}
```

**Why does this problem occur?**

Comment: You need to [register the nib](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618083-register), not the class for your cell.

Comment: Check imageView `IBOutlet` link in `CustomCell.xib`

Comment: Thank you! Now it's working perfectly! If any of you would like to post the answer down there I would accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to register the nib, not the class for your cell.

```
myCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName:"CustomCell.xib",bundle:nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you've created image view in XIB but have never registered it.

Either use this overloads:
    .register(UINib(*,*), forCell:"Cell")

Or delete xib , and manage all layout programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the File's Owner of that XIB is the ViewController hosting your `CustomCell`